# Pointer incrementing in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, increment

What does this mean: that a pointer increment points to the address of the next base type of the pointer?
For example:

```
p1++;  // p1 is a pointer to an int
```

Does this statement mean that the address pointed to by `p1` should change to the address of the next `int` or it should just be incremented by 2 (assuming an `int` is 2 bytes), in which case the particular address may not contain an `int`?
I mean, if `p1` is, say, 0x442012, will `p1++` be 0x442014 (which may be part of the address of a double) or will it point to the next `int` which is in an address like 0x44201F?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic doesn’t care about the content – or validity – of the pointee. It will simply increment the pointer address using the following formula:

```
new_value = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + sizeof(*p);
```

(Assuming a pointer to non-`const` – otherwise the cast wouldn’t work.)

That is, it will increment the pointer by an amount of `sizeof(*p)` bytes, regardless of things like pointee value and memory alignment.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler will add `sizeof(int)` (usually 4) to the numeric value of the pointer. If p1 is 0x442012 before the increment, then after the increment it will be 0x442012 + 4 = 0x442016.

Mind you, 0x442012 is not a multiple of 4, so it is unlikely to be the address of a valid four-byte int, though it would be fine for your two-byte ints.

It certainly won't go looking for the next integer. That would require magic.

Answer (score 3):

p1++ gives rise to assembly language instructions which increment p1 by the size of what it points to.  So you get

`(char *)p1 = (char *)p1 + sizeof (object pointed to by p1)`

(When this question was answered) Typically an int is 4 bytes, so it would increment by 4, but it depends on the sizeof() on your machine.

It does *not* go to "the next int".

An example: assume a 4 byte address and p1 = 0x20424 (where p1 is an int*).  Then

`p1++`

would set the new value of p1 to 0x20428.  NOT 0x20425.

Comment: No. `p1++` means `p1 += 1`, nothing else.

Comment: @Konrad: Well, unless you overload the ++ operator. Ah, the joys are redefining the meaning of operators (and a great way to make enemies) ;-)

Comment: @Skizz Even that won’t change the meaning since you cannot *change* the meaning of operators, so on a pointer, `++` will always have the same effect.

Comment: @Konrad: `class p { public: void operator++(int){exit(0);}};int main (){p a; a++; std::cout << "End" << std::endl;};` There, `a++` now quits the program. I've seen programmers overload the `^` operator on a vector3d class to implement cross products! I know, it's a crime against programming.

Comment: @Skizz The whole discussion is about `p`/`p1` being a pointer. Otherwise the answer would be even more wrong because obviously `++` doesn’t in general add `sizeof whatever`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You said "no", but Scott's definition seems correct. It does not just add '1'. I just tried it; it added 4 to my pointer. I had `0x7fa28d402780` and then I had `0x7fa28d402784`. Doesn't that mean it adds `sizeof(whatever)` to the value, not 1?

Comment: @GregSchmit That's not how pointer arithmetic works. `p++` adds 1 to the pointer value. But you (and Scott) seem to think that the 1 refers to 1 *byte*. It doesn't. See my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I thought pointers were unsigned integers, so if 4 is added, the the value was incremented by 4. It's not as if the values don't exist in between. If I have an int pointer on my machine, incrementing it adds 4 to the value, but I can manually set it to a value in between. It just seems like this answerer said exactly what you said up top. Then you said 'no'.

Comment: @GregSchmit Ah, that’s where the confusion stems from. So: pointers are *not* unsigned integers. Pointers are pointers — a distinct type! *Under the hood*, many/all platforms implement pointers as unsigned integers. But `p++` isn’t performed under the hood, it’s performed in C++ space. And it is equivalent to `p += 1`, not to `p += 4` or anything else. `p += 1` in turn is translated *under the hood* to an increment of the pointer value by the pointee object size. Of course *his isn’t always 4*, and the type of the address implementation has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @GregSchmit And, to make this perfectly clear: this answer doesn’t say the same as my answer at all. My answer is talking about the under-the-hood pointer address (which is equivalent to writing the C++ code `reinterpret_cast<char*>(p)`), not the C++ pointer itself. These are fundamentally different things.

Comment: @KonradRudolph That makes sense; yeah, I just tried to do `p+=sizeof(*p)` and it ends up going `sizeof(*p)` squared spaces, since you're (for `int` 4-byte as example) telling it `p+=4` and then under the hood it increments the raw data 4 for each one of those. I understand better now why it is wrong to say that it increments 4. Thanks.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The intention of my answer was to show what was happening under the hood - I updated it and hopefully made it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

If `p1` is pointing into the element of index `n` of an array of objects of type `int` (a non-array object counts as an array of length 1 for this purpose), then after `p1++`, `p1` is either:

- Pointing to the element of index `n+1` if the array is of length greater than `n+1`.
- The 'past-the-end' address of the array, if the array is of length exactly `n+1`.

`p1++` causes undefined behavior if `p1` is not pointing to an element of an array of objects of type `int`.

The only meaning that the C and C++ languages give to the notion of "address" is the value of a pointer object.

Any relationship that C/C++'s notion of address has to the notion of a numeric addresses you'd consider in assembly language is purely an implementation detail (albeit, an extremely common implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

Pointer arithmetic are done in `sizoeof(*pointer)` multiples - that is, for a pointer to int, increment will advance to the next integer (or 4 bytes for 32 bit integers).

Comment: "4 bytes for a 32 bit integer", well, that's not always true is it. Better say "(32 / CHAR_BIT) bytes in a 32 bit integer" (using the C++ definition of byte of course). But then again, who says integers are 32 bit?

Comment: There are hardly any architectures with a byte size different than 8 bits anymore. The `int` type is not necessarily 32 bits, but a "32 bit integer" is. I don't see you point...

Comment: There are numerous micro-controllers and DSPs that have weird configurations (there's a TI chip where all types are 16 bit).

Comment: @Skizz, I didn't said they were no architectures with a byte size different than 8 - I said there are hardly any. If you look into most (and perhaps all) of the (modern) CPUs and MCUs you'd see 8-bit bytes. DSPs are indeed wierd creatures. Some are 24 or 32 bits per byte.