# IntPointer to CharArray and type informations in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, types

my program

```
int main() {
     int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
     char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
     int* int_pointer = char_array;
     char* char_pointer = int_array;

     for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
         printf("[Integer pointer] points to %p, which contains the char '%c'\n", int_pointer, *int_pointer);
         int_pointer += 1;
     }

     for(int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
         printf("[Char pointer] points to %p, which contains the integer %d\n", char_pointer, *char_pointer);
         char_pointer += 1;
     }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff810, which contains the char 'a'
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff814, which contains the char 'e'    
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff818, which contains the char '8'
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff81c, which contains the char '
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff820, which contains the char '?'
[char pointer] points to 0xbffff7f0, which contains the char '1'
[char pointer] points to 0xbffff7f1, which contains the char '0'
[char pointer] points to 0xbffff7f2, which contains the char '0'
[char pointer] points to 0xbffff7f3, which contains the char '0'
[char pointer] points to 0xbffff7f4, which contains the char '2'
```

Taken into account the fact that I'm a newbie in the C language and computer science in general, I just don't get why the int_pointer on the one hand contains the information of moving forward four bytes when incrementing, but on the other hand only reads one byte at a time, whereas the char_pointer moves forward one byte at a time and only reads one byte at a time. So which information does the int_pointer (char_pointer) exactly contain? In my logic, where all information is contained in the pointer, it doesn't make any sense why the int_pointer (with integers being a data structure with four bytes length) only reads one byte at a time, but moves forward four bytes at a time. Where is the information stored that it should only read one byte instead of four bytes (although the int_pointer is declared as an int, which means it should read four bytes at a time)? The contradiction in this logic lies in the fact that if all the information would be stored in the pointer, then why does the char_pointer (declared one byte) read and jump (if incremented) one byte at a time, but the int_pointer (declared four bytes) reads and jumps (if incremented) four bytes at a time?

The output I expected, in the case of the int_pointer, would be the following:

```
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff810, which contains the char 'abcd'
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff814, which contains the char 'eUNDEFINEDSTUFF'    
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff818, which contains the char 'UNDEFINEDSTUFF'
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff81c, which contains the char 'UNDEFINEDSTUFF'
[integer pointer] points to 0xbffff820, which contains the char 'UNDEFINEDSTUFF'
```

I hope I made clear which point I'm exactly not understanding, thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: This don't compile, please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Uh, it reads one `char` at a time _because you tell it to_? And pointers increment by their stride size because otherwise they just wouldn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer incrementing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492408/pointer-incrementing-in-c)

Comment: @underscore_d what exactly do you mean by i tell it to?

Comment: You dereference the pointer-to-`int`, thus reading `sizeof(int)` bytes to create a temporary `int` from that memory, and pass the resulting (temporary) `int` to `printf`. However, you then tell `printf` to reinterpret that `int` as a `char`, so it reads whatever the first byte in memory is for that `int` and displays it as a `char`. The answer already states this.

Comment: Anyway, this is technically invalid code because `int* int_pointer = char_array;` breaks aliasing rules and is not required to work.

Comment: In the second printf you dereference the char and give the printf an int, so you read 1 byte and fill up the other 3 bytes with 0 to print it out as an integer?
And in the first printf, what exactly does it read in as the integer? Does it read in the bits of "a, b, c, d" or something else?
And do you have an idea where i could read about this? @underscore_d

Comment: I don't find these questions very useful as what you are doing is undefined behaviour, so the compiler is allowed to make it do anything. You should only tell `printf`, or any other function, to interpret objects as the type they genuinely have. Otherwise, the code is ill-formed, the compiler might do anything, and reasoning about it is not useful. Are you sure you didn't get the `%c` and %d` the wrong way around in your calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a character for 'abcd'.
The program is doing exactly what you might expect. Inside memory, the characters are stored as so...

```
[   a   ][   b   ][   c   ][   d   ][   e   ]
```

You point the integer pointer at the beginning of a and say to read a character (1 byte), so it reads one byte, a. Then you increment the integer pointer.

```
before: [   a   ][   b   ][   c   ][   d   ][   e   ] stuff.......
                 ^ pointer
after:  [   a   ][   b   ][   c   ][   d   ][   e   ] stuff.......
                                                    ^ pointer
```

Now the pointer has moved 4 bytes and points at e. You say to read 1 byte, so it does and outputs e. From here on, you experience unexpected behavior as you see with 8, the blank, and the ?.

Now for the integer array. Each integer is 4 bytes, where 1 is
0000.....00001. The point is, the one is at the far right.

When you arrange this in memory it looks like so:

```
[00000000][00000000][00000000][00000001] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000010] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000011] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000100] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000101] and more stuff....
```

You place your pointer so:

```
[00000000][00000000][00000000][00000001] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000010] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000011] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000100] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000101] and more stuff....
                                       ^ pointer
```

and you tell it to read 1 byte by dereferencing the char pointer, so you provide 00000001 to the %d in your printf. Then you increment

```
[00000000][00000000][00000000][00000001] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000010] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000011] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000100] [00000000][00000000][00000000][00000101] and more stuff....
                                                   ^ pointer
```

You tell it to read one byte through your dereference and it provides a bunch of 0s to your printf, printing out a 0. A couple loops later, your pointer reaches the 00000010 and prints out a 2. If you kept going some more, you'd have 3 more 0s and a 3, 3 more 0s and a 4, and so on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: nitpick: `int`s are not required to have that memory layout.

Comment: Hey, the question i have for this explanation is, where exactly do i tell each pointer to read one byte? Where does the dereferencing take place? What does dereferencing mean in this context?

Comment: Dereferencing is the concept of taking a pointer of some type and retrieving its real value. So for instance, char* a points to a memory address for a value. *a is the value pointed to by a. In your printf where you go printf(".... %p....%d", char_pointer, *char_pointer), you're essentially doing printf(...., memory location, some value); Since the pointer was a character pointer, it grabs one byte even though %d can display 32 bit values. So in summary, dereferencing ( *char_pointer ) provided you with a one byte value even though you provided it to %d.